# Django show form fields optionally

Tags: django-forms

I' creating comment system and I'd like to have different form rendering for registered users and anonymous user. Here is an idea:
**For anonymous users:**

```
Name:|     |
E-mail:|     |
Text:
 ________________
|                |
|                |
|________________|
```

**For registered users**

```
Text:
 ________________
|                |
|                |
|________________|
```

Here is my code:
**models.py**

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    """
    Class for comments
    """
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='comments')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    body = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)
```

**forms.py**

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    Form for adding comments
    """
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('title', 'email', 'body')
```

What's the best approach here?

I though of making e-mail and name both blank=True and null=True and populate them in custom save method. Add in view `if user.is_authenticated` and show fields accordingly but I don't know if it's OK. Could you recommend me best practices?

Answer (score 0):

Came up with this solution:
**in forms.py**

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Differend fields for auth and non-auth user
        """
        user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super(CommentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # if user and user.is_authenticated():
        del self.fields['name']
        del self.fields['email']
```

**in views.py**

```
....
    if request.method == 'POST':
    comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST)
    if comment_form.is_valid():
        new_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
        new_comment.post = post
        if user.is_authenticated():
            new_comment.author = User.objects.get(username=user.username)
            new_comment.email = User.objects.get(email=user.email)
        new_comment.save()
....
```